# How to make the main menu like Stackoverflow in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

How can I custom the output menu like stack in drupal 7. The main menu link appear above and the sub-menu link appear below, or some menu styles like this.

In Bartik theme, the $main_menu variable only content primary menu information but no child. So I must custom this variable or do something else to solve my problem ? Here is what i said:

```
<div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $main_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'main-menu-links',
        'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use drupal's standard menu output with `parent menu items` and `sub menu items`, then customize the appearance to your liking using CSS and javaScript.

You can benefit from the fact of that the `sub menu items` will appear ONLY for an active parent.

Just make sure that `Mark as expanded` for ALL `parent menu items` is checked off so they don't show by default.

**Update**:

Don't print out the menu in the template file. Instead, create a region in the same position then install [menu block module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block).

This way is more flexible than yours and gives you more options to control your menu (like the depth of sub items).

Check [the module documentation](http://drupal.org/node/748022) for more details. `Configuring menu blocks` section.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Please give me more information, what function I need to customise the menu output? Where should I do it, in my module or in my theme folder?

Comment: I've update my answer. Let me know if you still can't get it to work.